# A bit confusion with exists in karate?

Tags: karate

I am using exist for an element whose visibility is conditional like this

```
* if (locate('#elusivePopup').exists) click('#elusiveButton')
```

But when the element is not visible it gives an error as "cannot find locator #elusivePopup"?

version 0.9.6.RC4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This changed in 0.9.6.RCX https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1148

```
* if (exists('#epp')) click('#eb')
```

Comment: I am trying to update my maven dependency to 0.9.6RCX but it shows "no dependency information available"

Comment: @Ninja 0.9.6.RC4 is the latest. if you still have a problem follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Sorry my bad its my mistake